# error: Static member copyWithZone cannot be used on instance of type UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

```
class MDCollectionViewLayoutAttributes : UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
{
    var color: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    var image : UIImageView!

    override func copyWithZone(zone: NSZone) -> AnyObject
    {
        let newAttributes: MDCollectionViewLayoutAttributes = super.copyWithZone(zone) as! MDCollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        newAttributes.color = self.color.copyWithZone(zone) as! UIColor
        newAttributes.image = UIImageView(frame:newAttributes.bounds)
        newAttributes.image.image = UIImage(named:"Appetizer.png")

        newAttributes.image = self.image.copyWithZone(zone) as! UIImageView// this is giving me an error
        return newAttributes
    }
}
```

I need to declare an image to use it in the following code to set it as an section background, but its giving me an error.

```
override func layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]?
{
    let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect)
    var allAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    if let attributes = attributes
    {

        for attr in attributes
        {
            if (attr.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategory.Cell && attr.frame.origin.x == self.sectionInset.left)
            {
                                   let decorationAttributes = SBCollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forDecorationViewOfKind: "sectionBackground", withIndexPath: attr.indexPath)

              //  decorationAttributes.color = UIColor.brownColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(1)
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 0):

UIImageView does not conform to NSCopying protocol that's why copyWithZone is not working. You can create an extension to UIImageView or its subclass where you implement NSCopying conformance.

Comment: is there any example? or any link for an example?